# Need help parsing json file using gson

Tags: android, gson

Edit: I've changed the style of the json file to make it simpler as I couldn't work with the older version. I need to be able to create an array of targets in java where each element in the array has its name as the value of Target_Name. I also need to be able to merge together repeating target names that have different object names. So basically I want a target array and within each element I want to have an array of objects holding Type, Pin_number and capabilities.

I know I may have to create a Target list class and within that variables for target name and everything else. I have tried something like that before but I had trouble figuring out how it would work.

```
    {
"Targets": [
    {
        "Target_Name": "----",
        "Object_Name": "----",
        "Type": "----",
        "Pin_Number": "----",
        "Capabilities": "----"
    },
    {
        "Target_Name": "----",
        "Object_Name": "----",
        "Type": "----",
        "Pin_Number": "----",
        "Capabilities": "----"
    },
    {
        "Target_Name": "----",
        "Object_Name": "----",
        "Type": "----",
        "Pin_Number": "----",
        "Capabilities": "----"
    },
    {
        "Target_Name": "----",
        "Object_Name": "----",
        "Type": "----",
        "Pin_Number": "----",
        "Capabilities": "----"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: What a warm welcome to stackoverflow my friend @CodeDroid. Maybe save that for non first-timers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward, following is some code how to load and read nodes. It will help you to find out how to query your data.

```
Reader reader = null;
InputStream stream = context.getResources()
    .openRawResource(R.raw.json_file);
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream), 8092);

// parse json
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsonObj = (JsonObject)parser.parse(reader);
```

// your json parsing is going to look like following

```
JsonArray targets= jsonObj.getAsJsonArray("Targets");

List<Target> targetList = new ArrayList<Target>(); 
for (JsonElement target: targets) {

    JsonObject targetObject = target.getAsJsonObject();
    String targetName= targetObject.get("Target_Name").getAsString();
    ....//get the rest

    // create target object
    targetList.add(new Target(targetName, ....));
}
```

// Examples of how to read values and query objects

```
for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : rootElem.entrySet())
{
    int key = Integer.parseInt(entry.getKey());
    JsonObject jsonObject = entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject();
}


// get integer element
int key = Integer.parseInt(entry.getKey());

// get child object
JsonObject jsonObject = entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject();

// get string element           
String title = jsonObject.get("Object_Name").getAsString();
```

Comment: file is not a rawresource. I have an http connection to google cloud and have a url to the json file. The problem is parsing this file and saving those variables for later use. I'll try to implement the other things you've mentioned though.

Comment: @user1586194 it doesn't matter what is the source of json file, just read it from anywhere to the Reader or simply String and give to the JsonParser.parse() method.

Comment: Are JsonParser and JsonObject not part of the json class that is included in android sdk? Does gson have an equivalent?

Comment: @user1586194 I am talking only about com.google.gson.* lib. Which wasn't included by the time (a year ago) I was working with it

Comment: I'll have to finish this tomorrow. I'll give an update if it worked the way I want and give you the check mark for correct answer.

Comment: I've updated my question. I think it will make it simpler to parse.

Comment: @user1586194 I updated my answer, it should help you to understand how to do your parsing.

Comment: I see where you are going with this and it probably will work. The only problem I have right now is that the line String targetName= target.get("Target_Name").getAsString(); doesn't work. I get "The method get(String) is undefined for the type JsonElement"

Comment: @user1586194 updated. You have to play a bit with the objects, debug and see what is going on and what you can get. I cannot write working code in the notepad.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I managed to create the list of targets even though there are repeated target names still. I should be able to go on from here. Btw I just had to remove the line JsonObject rootElem = (JsonObject)listJson.get("Targets")); and change the line after that to use listJson instead of rootElem